# How good are heartbeat, elasticsearch and kibana as a monitoring/alerting solution as a replacement for Nagios?

Tags: elastic

Since we already have filebeat, metricbeat and heartbeat configured and running.

I wonder if people have successfully implemented the ELK stack for actual monitoring with alerting/notifications instead of using traditional software as

- Nagios
- Icinga
- Zabbix

Especially since ElasticSearch now has had watchers and alerting for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself, but in [Alarms management with Elasticsearch and Kibana](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1188/alarms-management-with-elasticsearch-and-kibana) someone recommended [Elastalert](http://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elastalert.html)